# Checking user credentials with Android Saripaar

Tags: android, saripaar

I am trying to create a custom rule using Android Saripaar to check the validity of login credentials a user has input but I am unable to figure out how to create a custom rule that accepts 2 inputs. All of the examples I have seen only accept 1 input whereas I need to pass in a username and password then head off to an api for validation.

Does anybody know of any good examples out there for this?

Thanks

Comment: Is this about v1 or v2? If v2, are you trying to create a custom annotation or a `QuickRule`?

Comment: it is v2. I dont mind either way, an annotation would be better then I could re-use it alot easier. currently I am doing it manually in a seperate method but it would be bteer for consistency to create a proper rule for it